# Feynman diagram: Two-way arrow in the fermion propagator line?

Tags: feynman-diagrams, fermions, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model, majorana-fermions

I have encountered some diagrams (like the example below) where two lines coming out of a single vertex (in this context, right-handed neutrino $N^c$) have opposite direction. In a usual diagram, a fermion propagator should have one direction only. Why is this different?

[image]

Comment: Encountered where? Which page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This propagator must come from Majorana fermion which satisfies the real condition i.e. there is only one kind of creation or annihilation operator in plane mode expansion:
\begin{align}
N^c=\int\overline{\mathrm{d}^3p}\left(e^{-ipx}\zeta a+e^{ipx}\eta a^{\dagger}\right)\,
\end{align}
where $\overline{\mathrm{d}^3k}$ is the one-particle covariant measure and $\zeta$ and $\eta $ are possible spinors which depend on representations.

As a consequence, $N^c$ could contract (Wick's contraction, recall that this contraction comes from $[a,a^\dagger]$) with $N^c$ itself, which generates this double arrow line.

But for Dirac fermion, there is only the contraction between $\psi$ and $\bar{\psi}$, which yields the one-way arrow from $\psi$ to $\bar{\psi}$ in the propagator.

There is the main difference between those two propagators in Feynman diagrams.